# How can I make Ubuntu VM image running in Multipass available in local network?

Tags: ubuntu, multipass

I've created an Ubuntu Core 18.04 LTS VM image instance in Multipass running on my Ubuntu Dekstop environment. I'd like to make the Ubuntu Core VM image instance's IPv4 static and available in the Ubuntu Desktop machine's LAN. When configuring the Ubuntu Core VM image such that it uses DHCP to get an IPv4 address it's in the range of the Ubuntu Host machine's interface for the "Multipass interface" e.g. `mpqemubr0` (fictitious):

```
mpqemubr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.200.30.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.200.30.255
    ...
```

Let's say the LAN is in the IPv4 address space `192.168.178.0/24`. How do I have to configure Ubuntu Core and/or Multipass that Ubuntu Core is available in the LAN?

EDIT: It turned out that [bridged networking is not supported in multipass yet](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/118). I'm still looking for a workaround.